# Умное сворачивание сайдбаров js

Tags: javascript, html

Есть 2 сайдбара. Левый/правый, оба она сворачиваются/разворачиваются. Но задача состоит в том чтобы при ширине обертки <1500px выполнялись чуть другие условия , а именно:

*У меня экран 1280px* - при заходе на сайт развернут только левый сайдбар (то есть правый при таком разрешении скрыт) (*по умолчанию (>1500px) оба сайдбара развернуты*). При попытке развернуть правый, сворачивается левый , и открывается правый. и наоборот.

Так как js , я только постепенно начинаю изучать, набросал мега костильный вариант.

Как реализовать это более правильно и не костыльно?

```js
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(){
      $("#left-menu").toggleClass("menu-hidden");
      $(".wide-mode").toggleClass("menu-hidden");
      $(".wide-mode").toggleClass("menu-show");
    });

    $("#right-menu-toggle").click(function(){
      $(".wide-mode").addClass("chat-hidden");
      $(".wide-mode").toggleClass("chat-show");

    });

    $("#right-menu-show").click(function(){
      $(".wide-mode").removeClass("chat-hidden");
      $(".wide-mode").addClass("chat-show");
    });

  $(window).resize(function(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if(windowWidth < 1500) {
        $("#right-menu-show").click(function(){
        $("#left-menu").addClass("menu-hidden");
        $(".wide-mode").addClass("menu-hidden");
        $(".wide-mode").removeClass("menu-show");
        });

        $("#menu-toggle").click(function(){
        $(".wide-mode").addClass("chat-hidden");
        $(".wide-mode").removeClass("chat-show");
        });
    }
    else {
        
    }
  });

  $(window).resize(function(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if(windowWidth < 1500) {
    $(".wide-mode").addClass("menu-hidden");
    $(".wide-mode").addClass("chat-hidden");
    $("#left-menu").addClass("menu-hidden");
    $(".wide-mode").removeClass("chat-show");
    $(".wide-mode").removeClass("menu-show");
    }
    else {
        $("#left-menu").removeClass("menu-hidden");
        $(".wide-mode").removeClass("menu-hidden");
        $(".wide-mode").removeClass("chat-hidden");
    }
  });
```

Comment: Или можно просто оптимизировать этот код? Ибо тут явно есть много-чего лишнего.

Comment: приведите ваш хтмл-код, цсс-код, добавьте jquery и сделайте из этого запускаемый пример. пока что ваш код невозможно оценить